# Ant @ variable not resolved

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

Here is my snippet of build.xml

```
<target name="compile">
  <for param="rsync.destination.host" list="${file}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
    <sequential>
    <echo message="${rsync.ssh.user}@@{rsync.destination.host}:${rsync.destination.base.dir}/"/>
    </sequential>
  </for>
</target>
```

I received following output,

```
compile:
     [echo] root@{rsync.destination.host}:/tmp/
     [echo] root@{rsync.destination.host}:/tmp/

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

So here `@{rsync.destination.host}` variable is not interpreted because of double @@ character. If I put space in between them

```
    <echo message="${rsync.ssh.user}@ @{rsync.destination.host}:${rsync.destination.base.dir}/"/>
```

then variable is resolved as expected.

```
compile:
     [echo] root@ server1:/tmp/
     [echo] root@ server2:/tmp/

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Since there is space in username and server it will through exception if we perform ssh here. Any idea how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no variables in (core) ant, but properties and attributes.
 @{foo} is the syntax for accessing the value of a macrodef attribute inside a macrodef. As [antcontrib for task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) uses [ant macrodef task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) under the hood it has the same syntax.
Try with :

```
...
<echo message="${rsync.ssh.user}@@@{rsync.destination.host}:${rsync.destination.base.dir}/"/>
...
```

means use 3x @ instead of 2x @
The param `@{rsync.destination.host}` has to be masked with a second @, so in fact you need to use @ 3 times.

Comment: Thank you for solution but here in case of 4x@ I only required 3x@. Will you please edit your answer so that I will marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the literal at-sign in a property:

```
<property name="at" value="@"/>
<echo message="${rsync.ssh.user}${at}@{rsync.destination.host}:${rsync.destination.base.dir}/"/>
```